# How to read the Austrian Robinson list with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

The Austrian Commercial Opt-Out list is provided as raw binary file with sha-1 hash values each 20 bytes. How to read and convert it to VARCHAR2 with PL/SQL.

Comment: Can you explain more about exactly what the binary file format is?  There are billions of ways that character data might be represented in a binary file format-- we can probably help you if you can be more specific about the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the answer:
The additional email address is just for verification of the conversion.
The test hash file is taken from the official Austrian website: http://www.rtr.at/de/tk/nutzenecg

```
DECLARE
  vInHandle  utl_file.file_type;
  V1 RAW(32767);
  vEmail VARCHAR2(200) := 'karl.testinger@firma.at';
BEGIN
  --open file 
  vInHandle := utl_file.fopen('RECEIVE', 'testliste.hash', 'R');
  --read raw 20 bytes
  UTL_FILE.GET_RAW(vInHandle,V1,20); 
  --convert raw 20 bytes to HEX
  dbms_output.put_line('Compiled hash:'||LOWER (TO_CHAR (RAWTOHEX (v1))));

  --convert email to hash
  dbms_output.put_line('Email hash:   '||LOWER (sys.dbms_crypto.HASH(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(vEmail),sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh1))); 



END fopen;
/
```

If both outputs are the same, everything is working fine. The ORACLE user must have grants to execute the dbms_crypto package.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using binary large objects / large objects (blobs) for storing and reading binary file formats.